# Understanding SeleniumGrid

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to implement selenium grid being new to selenium2 .What i can't understand is do we actually need to have our node which we register with the hub have the configurations which we specify in our test.
By this I mean : say my machine which has windows on it,can I register it as node with the hub having configurations platform:LINUX,browserName:firefox or can I only register my machine as windows type?

I tried with Linux-firefox and my test passed also.But am not clear how can it run on a linux platform,if my machine was Windows

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role webdriver
```

`-browser "browserName=firefox,platform=LINUX" -hub` `http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently have a Hub that is in Linux and several windows nodes and don't have an issue.  When I register the HUB machine, I use the following code from the command prompt:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub
```

Then, from each node machine, I run the a variant of the following code...depending on what configuration I want:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\selenium\chromedriver.exe -   Dwebdriver.iexplorer.driver=c:\selenium\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://<YOURHUBSERVER>:4444/grid/register -port 6660 -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=0 -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=3 -browser browserName=iexplorer,maxInstances=0 -maxSessions=3
```

Just make sure the node computer has the jar file and all your paths are correct.
Once you do this, you will be able to see them in your Grid configuration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No what my question was I have say HUB SERVER WINDOWS TYPE but my NODES ,can they be of type LINUX or say MAC? without my nodes actually havig the defined platforms installed.What I mean was my node is of type windows but in my command prompt I configure it to be Linux .Hope you got my query?Am confused with the concept.Do I need to have the platforms which I am specifying ,available on the machines which am defining as NODE.

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the OS.  If you start the hub and then connect the nodes with the correct URL...the hub will automatically detect.  The Hub doesn't care what operating system is installed...only that it can communicate.

Comment: but how would my tests run on a particular configuration ,I mean I want my tests to run on Linux,firefox say..If my node doesn't have Linux installed how would my tests run on linux platform

Comment: Ahh...I think I understand now.  You would just need to specify which capability you want when you register each node such as browserName=firefox,platform=LINUX.  You would need to run the node registration script on the targeted Linux machine.  If your script called for a Linux configuration and you didn't have a Linux node, I assume it wouldn't run.  Also...if you say a windows computer is a linux computer and you are calling for a linux node, I assume the test would run as it would see a match.

Comment: :)yes then it means you are saying ,my tests would run on linux config even though my machine is windows but it wouldnt be accurate as my machine is actually a windows machine.I was wondering why my tests passed as my machine was windows even though I declared it to be Linux.

Comment: Great!  Hope this all helps in some way.

Comment: If this satisfies your questions, please mark it as answered by check the checkmark.  Thank You!